# How to add URLs to bubble chart?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to add clickable URLs to the bubble chart at: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269

I've tried modifying the *circle* node so that it reads:

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://en.wikipedia.org")
...
```

However I this does not work. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should attach click event to the circles.

```
node.append('circle')
    .on('click', d => {
        window.open("http://en.wikipedia.org", "_blank")
    })
```

Comment: Genius. Just to add, that I replaced window.open with window.location = url;

Comment: Great, please mark the question as answered if it solved your problem